# index argument contains . perl

Tags: perl, indexing

If a string contains `.` representing any character, index doesn't match on it. What to do so that it takes `.` as any character?

For ex,

```
index($str, $substr)
```

if `$substr` contains `.` anywhere, index will always return `-1`

thanks

carol

Comment: I need to know the position of the first occurrence of $substr or substring as it may be in the $str more than once

Comment: $substr=".AMBSDF"
$str="KFSDkfslsdfsBAMBSDFdkf"

12th position in $str, always the first character that $substr is found in $str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. The [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) says:

> The index function searches for one string within another, but without
>   the wildcard-like behavior of a full regular-expression pattern match.
>
> ...

The keywords, you can use for further googlings are:

- perl regular expression wildcard

Update:

If you just want to know, if your string matches, using a regular expression could look like that:

```
my $string   = "Hello World!";

if( $string =~ /ll. Worl/ )
{
    print "Ahoi! Position: ".($-[0])."\n";
}
```

This is matching a single character.

> $-[0] is the offset into the string of the beginning of the entire
>   match.

-- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

If you want to have a pattern, that is matching an arbitary amount of arbitary characters, you could choose a pattern like...

```
...

if( $string =~ /ll.*orl/ )
{

...
```

See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for further information about special perl variables. You will find the variable `@LAST_MATCH_START` and some explanation about `$-[0]` over there. There are several more variables, that can help you to find sub matches and to gather other interessting information about your matches...

Comment: I need to know the position of the first occurrence of $pattern or substring

Comment: Hey carol, edited the answer to contain information about the occurrence : )

Comment: btw - I just noticed in your profile, that you normally don't choose an answer. I'd like to ask you to do that ;D

Answer (score 1):

From `perldoc -f index`, you can see `index()` doesn't have any regex syntax:

```
index STR,SUBSTR
               The index function searches for one string within another, but without the wildcard-like behavior of a full regular-
               expression pattern match.  It returns the position of the first occurrence of SUBSTR in STR at or after POSITION.  If
               POSITION is omitted, starts searching from the beginning of the string.  POSITION before the beginning of the string or after
               its end is treated as if it were the beginning or the end, respectively.  POSITION and the return value are based at 0 (or
               whatever you've set the $[ variable to--but don't do that).  If the substring is not found, "index" returns one less than the
               base, ordinarily "-1"
```

A simple test:

```
$ perl -e 'print index("1234567asdfghj.","j.")'
13
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
$str =~ /$substr/g;
$index = pos();
```